# Remove duplicate Promise polyfill in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Babel, which imports `core-js/modules/es6.promise`, and fast-async, which imports `nodent-runtime/zousan`. They're both Promise polyfills and I need only one of them. How can I remove one?

I tried these in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'core-js/modules/es6.promise': 'nodent-runtime/zousan',
    },
  },
```

.

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      './zousan': 'core-js/modules/es6.promise',
    },
  },
```

However, neither worked.

Comment: that doesn't appear to be the default config for fast-async from the docs here: https://github.com/MatAtBread/fast-async#promises-polyfill